# Background not filling in completely

Tags: html, css, background

For some reason the background on my website is not loading fully. Randomly, not all the time, the website will load with white rectangles around the content of the website. Check out this [screenshot](http://thinkitpostit.com/wierd.jpg) to get a better picture, or visit [www.thinkitpostit.com](http://www.thinkitpostit.com/) to see if it randomly happens for you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me Google Chrome 6.0.408.1 dev on Lucid Lynx. I hope you got some revenue from my taking a look from one of the zillon ad-mongers the page references.

Comment: What browsers have you seen this happen in? Using Chrome it happened to me. I've noticed, however, that Chrome doesn't always draw the background of the body to fill the entire window if the page is shorter than the window itself. EDIT: I'm using Chrome 4.1.249.1064 (45376) on XP Pro SP2, if you care.

Comment: On the other hand, that's a pretty attractively composed front-page.

Comment: @msw what do you mean by "I hope you got some revenue from my taking a look from one of the zillon ad-mongers the page references.", thanks for the kind words though

@Jeff Hmmm, I did notice it seems to only happen in Chrome

Comment: I just saw a huge block of javascript with various web advertisers named in it. I didn't care enough to look more closely; please insert an implied smiley in my comment about the ad-mongers.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's just the way Chrome displays the page on certain loads. I can't find a rhyme or reason as to why except that it does and I simply try to ignore it as best as possible. Every other browser seems to be intelligent enough to do it correctly.

Comment: @msw Ah that stuff was from Google tools I was giving a shot. :)

@Jeff I am surprised this is ONLY happening in Chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a

```
width:800px;
```

on your body tag.

This could possibly cause some trouble since the background color is placed on the body tag.
I would generally recommend to not use any width or height properties on the body tag.

Comment: I will give this a shot and get back.